# How to do something like someRef.on('child_changed', callbackFunction); for cloud functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to convert an existing node.js server code to serverless cloud functions.
In one of my functions, I have a frigger on realtime database using "child_changed", which triggers not only when the child is changed, but when the children of the child is changed as well.

In cloud functions, I am using onWrite:

```
ref("users/{app}/{user}").onWrite((snapshot, context)=>{
...
})
```

However, this only works when a new node is added at the location or that specific child is updated. How can I trigger the function even for inner children?

//old code

```
someRef..on('child_added', callbackFunction);
```

//cloud function code

```
ref("users/{app}/{user}").onWrite((snapshot, context)=>{
...
})
```

Comment: I wrote an answer on how triggers work below. If your code doesn't work, edit your question to show exactly what doesn't work please.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, Thank you for your answer. I does trigger the function when I change child nodes of user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this declaration:

```
ref("users/{app}/{user}").onWrite(
```

The Cloud Function will be triggered whenever any user under any app is written. If you write lower level data under that user node, the function will also be triggered. The `snapshot` argument has all data under the user that triggered the write operation.